# How to correctly fill a UITableView with asynchronous content that needs to be sorted

Tags: uitableview, ios7, nssortdescriptor, nsmetadataquery

I have a bunch of files in various sizes (>100) stored in iCloud. I have a `NSMetadataQuery` that returns these files. They are reported to my app from the `NSMetadataQuery` object in random order.

I open them and extract a couple of strings which then get sorted and displayed in a `UITableView`.

I have tried two approaches:
A) loading each file, sorting the array of files informations, and calling `reloadData` on the `UITableView` each time.
and B) waiting for all the files to have loaded and then sort the "full" array and then call `reloadData` once.

Option B is obviously better but basically takes just as long for the user to see results. 
How does one do this best?

Do I need to extract the data I display in the `UITableView` into a different file (i.e. PLIST), so that I can load that quicker and display it while the actual data is being loaded in the background?
Or do I need to basically extend implementation A by keeping track of the Array and then calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` for each row that subsequently gets changed due to the sort?

What is the best practice for this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a user point of view, faster is better, and seeing something, even incomplete, is better than seeing nothing. So:

1. If you can maintain an index file which lists this information, use that for the display and download only what you need (like your Plist idea, but probably stored in iCloud, maybe in the key/value store)
2. If you have to download file info, show the user an activity indicator so they know you're still working and add items to the UI as you get them (your option A)

Changing from `reloadData` to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` makes for better animations, so is nice to have but not required and doesn't make things faster.

Comment: I was kind of hoping this was not the solution. Because it makes storing display information with the file itself kind of redundant. But I guess it is like making my own index-table in a database. Thanks for the quick reply.